# Why can I not check if Flutter list isnotempty?

Tags: arrays, flutter, if-statement

I have created a flutter list but how do I check if it is empty?
`List<int> selectedItems = [];`
However, `selectedItems.isNotEmpty` gives me `Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.` error. How do I fix this?

I created a dropdown

```
SearchChoices.multiple(
                        clearIcon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.times),
                        underline: Container(
                          color: const Color(0xffF0F0F0),
                        ),
                        items:
                            _list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        selectedItems: selectedItems,
                        hint: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Text("Select any"),
                        ),
                        searchHint: "Select any",
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            value = selectedItems;
                          });
                        },
                        closeButton: (selectedItems) {
                          return selectedItems.isNotEmpty
                              ? "Save ${selectedItems.length == 1 ? '"' + items[selectedItems.first].value.toString() + '"' : '(' + selectedItems.length.toString() + ')'}"
                              : "Save without selection";
                        },
                        isExpanded: true,
                      ),
```

The error is here

```
closeButton: (selectedItems) {
                          return selectedItems.isNotEmpty
                              ? "Save ${selectedItems.length == 1 ? '"' + items[selectedItems.first].value.toString() + '"' : '(' + selectedItems.length.toString() + ')'}"
                              : "Save without selection";
                        },
```

[image: Error]

The dropdown package I used is: https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

UPDATE
It seems that flutter sees the `List<int>` as a `dynamic` type. Ever since I began the project it has been assigning every variable as dynamic even if I specified its type.
[image]
Screenshot of variable
[image]

Comment: do you try this `  if(selectedItems.isNotEmpty){
    print("something");
  } else{
    print("empty");
  }`

Comment: the moment I type ```.isNotEmpty``` I get that error. It doesn't even show ```.isNotEmpty``` as one of the possible options for ```selectedItems```

Comment: show your code where you call from

Comment: Updated answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a type to the selectedItems,

According to the `searchable_dropdown` docs

> closeButton: String|Widget|Function with parameter: selectedItems returning String|Widget displayed at the bottom of the search dialog box.

```dart
closeButton: (List<int> selectedItems) {
                          return selectedItems.isNotEmpty
                              ? "Save ${selectedItems.length == 1 ? '"' + items[selectedItems.first].value.toString() + '"' : '(' + selectedItems.length.toString() + ')'}"
                              : "Save without selection";
                        },
```